# Aggregating MultiPoints to MultiPoint output using ST_Collect

Tags: postgis, aggregation, multipoint

I have a geometry column that stores MultiPoints. How can I aggregate MultiPoints having another MultiPoint as a result, not a GeometryCollection?

```sql
select st_collect(geom), id
from my_table
group by id
```

unfortunately leads to a GeometryCollection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) says:

> If any of the input geometries are collections (Multi* or
> GeometryCollection) ST_Collect returns a GeometryCollection (since
> that is the only type which can contain nested collections). To
> prevent this, use ST_Dump in a subquery to expand the input
> collections to their atomic elements (see example below).

```sql
SELECT
    stusps,
    ST_Collect(f.the_geom) AS geom
FROM (
    SELECT
        stusps,
        (ST_Dump(the_geom)).geom AS the_geom
    FROM
        somestatetable) AS f
GROUP BY
    stusps
```